# Multiple routers for express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a rather odd use case; I have two sources of URLs for my web application.  One is a set of custom URLs, the analysis of which is heavily dependent upon a large and somewhat arcane legacy application; the other is a new administrative layer for the application that my team has free rein to create whatever we want.  There's a well-defined list of "root" URLs, so we can safely allocate URLs for our new admin pages.

Is it possible to have *two* routers in Express.JS?  I've seen people inject their own routers into Express.JS, but the source code to Express seems to be deeply wedded to Route.js and the various definitive "methods" block.  I want to be able to scan one set of routes with their weird rules and, if there's no match *then* check the more routine (for Express) set of routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Write your own middleware function that handles the legacy URLs, and place it above the Express router.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    if (legacySystemHandles(req.url)) {
        // do legacy stuff
    }
    else next(); // pass to the next middleware function
});
app.use(app.router);
```

Or the other way around:

```
app.use('/admin', app.router); // mounts the router to a specific path
app.use(function(req, res) {
    // do legacy stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by putting the legacy router before the Express router in the middleware.

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(legacy.router); // pseudo code
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
}
```